# Place a checkbox in between of 2 rows jquery MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a `MVC` web app in which I show a table.
Some of my rows can have a similar id, on which I need to show only one `checkbox` for all those rows, and individual `checkboxes` for the rows which don't have a matching id. Something like below:

[image]

`row1` and `row2` have the same id, hence the `checkbox` is in between them (denoted by red `checkbox`).
`row3`, `row4` have different ids, hence they need to have their individual `checkboxes` (denoted by green).

I know I need to play on the `rowspan` property, but I am unable to visualize how to get on it.

```
Below is the sample code:

[Route("Search")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
{
 //Some API call
 return View("Search", model);
}
```

View Code:

```
<table id="tblsearch">
 @if (Model.HasRecords)
 {
 var counter = 0;
 <tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults)
   {
   <tr>                           
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Dummy_@counter" name="chkSearch" data-id="@item.Id"/>
            <label for="Dummy_@counter"></label>
       </td>
       <td>@item.FullAddress</td>
       <td>@item.Price</td>
        <td>@item.OfficeName</td>
     }
      else
      {
       <tr><td>Data Not Found</td></tr>
       }
     </table>
```

I am trying to first hide all the `checkboxes`, then trying to match the id's in each `row`, and then if the ids of 2 rows are same, I am trying to increase the `rowspan` by 2.

```
js code:

function pageLoad()
    {
        var rowCount = $('#tblSearch >tbody >tr').length;
        for(var i=0;i<rowCount-1;i++)
        {
            $('#Dummy_' + i).hide();
        }
        var searchArray= [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) {
            searchArray[i]= $('#tblSearch >tbody >tr')[i].attr('data-id');
        }        
    }
```

Please guide how to proceed.

Comment: seems to me that you should be controlling a rowspan on your checkbox cell that matches the number of occurances of ID in your results.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, you're right..something like that..any pointers or some sample code?

Comment: in that case you need to build the table itself in a loop.  in the loop you'll need to check how many "same ids follow contiguously" and then increase td.colspan by that number. of course in those following rows you'll want to avoid inserting a table cell at all.

Comment: Set them with different class attributes and control them with jquery by using $('.checkboxedrow').html('checkboxed') and vice versa.

Comment: @sweaver2112: Thanku for the suggestion..let me try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for any javascript. You can simply group your items by the `Id` property and conditionally render the checkbox column with a `rowspan` attribute if its the first item in the group.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var group in Model.SearchResults.GroupBy(x => x.Id))
    {
        bool isFirstRow = true;
        foreach (var item in group)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (isFirstRow)
                {
                    <td rowspan="@group.Count()">
                        @Html.CheckBox("chkSearch")
                    </td>
                    isFirstRow = false;
                }
                <td>@item.FullAddress</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
                <td>@item.OfficeName</td> 
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: @Stephen..I will try and will let you know..Thanks.

Comment: I had created [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vGnH6Z) to test it (but forgot to give you the link)

Comment: Thanks a lot. your solution helped greatly. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should control the layout of the page in this instance from your View, please forgive my syntax as I primarily work in vbhtml these days.

Important things are to order your search results (in case they aren't already)
Remember and update the last processed Id.

```
<table id="tblsearch">
@if (Model.HasRecords)
{
var counter = 0;
var lastId = -1;
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults.OrderBy(x=>x.Id))
    {
        <tr>                   
            @if(lastId!= item.Id){
            <td rowspan="@(Model.SearchResults.Count(x=>x.Id == item.Id) > 0 ? Model.SearchResults.Count(x=>x.Id == item.Id) : 1 )">
              <input type="checkbox" id="Dummy_@counter" name="chkSearch" data-id="@item.Id"/>
                <label for="Dummy_@counter"></label>
            </td>
            }
            <td>@item.FullAddress</td>
            <td>@item.Price</td>
            <td>@item.OfficeName</td>
            @lastId = item.Id;
            //I assume there was code snipped here...
}
else
{
<tr><td>Data Not Found</td></tr>
}
 </table>
```

Comment: Let me try..Thanku

Comment: come to think of it the rowspan conditional is redundant and could be just `rowspan="@Model.SearchResults.Count(x=>x.Id == item.Id)"`

Comment: @Steve..it works..but with certain anomalies...the checkbox with rowspan as 2 should come in between the 2 matching rows, but it comes in front of the first row.

Comment: that cell should span the rows.  some css might be required to make it look like its in the middle.  turn the borders on to see what I mean.

Comment: @Steve..Thanks a lot...your solution helped a lot.